# Should a new S3 client be initiated on every request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I am creating a simple CRUD api using NodeJS + TS and AWS SDK.
I configured AWSCognito and IAM services for accessing S3 resources.

User can for example request a service that returns all the objects in a S3 bucket. Because not all users should be able to read from S3 bucket, the user should be authenticated when calling the service.

Do I need to instantiate a new S3 client for every user request (and configure it with new user credentials)? If not, what is the best way to pass authenticated user credentials to AWS SDK client?